# How do I remove lines that are commented out along with the first line?

Tags: python, shell, sed

I have a file with the following format:

```
output data 
#comment1
#note3
#message5
#email2
1   5   7
10  4   1
2   6   1
```

I would like to remove the first line (that contains the  word output) and all lines that are commented out. The final file should look lie the following:

```
1   5   7
10  4   1
2   6   1
```

Is there a simply way to do this using shell and/or python? Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: What, if there was a commented line somewhere after the first uncommented line ("1 5 7' in your example) ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `sed`:

```
sed  '1d;/^[[:space:]]*#/d' file
```

- `1d` -> removes the first line
- `/^[[:space:]]*#/d` -> removes all lines that start with a `#`, optionally preceded by whitespace

Comment: alternative: `sed -i '/^#/d' <filepath>`

Comment: OP also asked to remove the first line.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution using Python. I am not sure whether you want to save the contents back. If you do, just write the resulting string back into the file.

Open the file and read its contents first:

```
In [8]: with open("file", "r") as f:
   ...:     contents = f.read()
   ...:
```

Then split the lines by line break and remove all the ones that start with a comment:

```
In [11]: mod_contents = [row for row in contents.split('\n') if not row.startswith("#")]
```

Then join the resulting lines:

```
In [14]: "\n".join(mod_contents[1:])
```